Date Field Not Outputting Correct Format on URL
I'm building out a form on a hotel for room reservations. Currently, a user can select a check-in and checkout date. When the user selects a check-in or checkout date the format comes through in the URL as yyyy-mm-dd and in the URL as examplesite.com/1234?datein=yyyy-mm-dd. How can I get the date output to be formatted as mm/dd/yyyy?
Currently, this is my input tag:
<input class="date_in" id="datein" placeholder="" value="" type="date" name="datein">


you can cut the string with this function : https://php.net/explode

Thank you @Ronak Hapailya and @mmm for your help. I figured out a different workaround because the output couldn't be modified in the format the travel software needed if the field remained a type="date" field.
This is what I did. I changed the field to a type="text" and made the text field show a datepicker UI.
The new code for the input fields:
<input class="date_in" id="DateIn" value="mm/dd/yyyy" type="text" name="DateIn">

<input class="date_out" id="DateOut" value="mm/dd/yyyy" type="text" name="DateOut">

Jquery to make the text field appear as a datepicker field:
jQuery(function($) {
  $('.date_in').each(function(){
    $(this).datepicker({ dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yy' }).val();
  });
  
  $('.date_out').each(function(){
    $(this).datepicker({ dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yy' }).val();
  });
});


As you cant change the input type date output formate. So instead of this you can change date formate in php
if (isset($_GET['datein'])) {
    $datein = $_GET['datein'];
    $date = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $datein);
    if ($date) {
        $formattedDate = $date->format('m/d/Y');
        echo 'Formatted Date: ' . $formattedDate;
    } else {
        echo 'Invalid date format.';
    }
}

like above sample code you can change date formate whatever you want.
